# Суммирование элементов списка

Tags: python

В тестовом задании необходимо разделить шестизначное число пополам и сравнить суммы двух частей на равенство.
Процесс завис на моменте, где потребовалось сложить значения первой половины списка: необходимо перевести значения переменной list_1 в целочисленные, но при запуске переменная по-прежнему остается в значении str. Какие способы замены переменной возможно применить в данном случае, чтобы суммировать значения из выделенного списка?
Заранее благодарю за помощь!

```
a=input('Введите шестизначный номер билета:')
if len(a) < 6:
    print("Слишком маленькое число. Введите шестизначный номер билета")
elif len(a) > 6:
    print('Слишком большое число. Введите шестизначный номер билета')
elif len(a) == 6:
     b=len(a)/2
     list_1 = a[:int(b)] *#как суммировать значения списка??*
     print(list_1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например, так:

```
a=input('Введите шестизначный номер билета:')
if len(a) < 6:
    print("Слишком маленькое число. Введите шестизначный номер билета")
elif len(a) > 6:
    print('Слишком большое число. Введите шестизначный номер билета')
else:
    digit_list = list(map(int, a))
    print(digit_list)
    print(sum(digit_list[:3]), sum(digit_list[3:]))
```

Comment: Космос! Все работает. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Marylink_27  OK, не забывайте про https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer